# Manipulate AWS base URL in the SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to change the base URL of the the AWS SDK for Java.
It is possible with the SDK for PHP like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

// Create a client that that contacts a completely customized base URL
$client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
'endpoint' => 'http://my-custom-url',
'region'   => 'my-region-1',
'credentials' => array(
    'key'      => 'abc',
    'secret'   => '123'
)
));
```

It's also possible to set this up for s3cmd in .s3conf:

```
host_base = s3.mylocalaws.com
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.s3.mylocalaws.com
```

I can't figure out how this works for the Java SDK.

I've tried this but the result is not https://s3.mylocalaws.com/bucketName/key as I expected but https://bucketName.s3.mylocalaws.com

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new AWSTestCredentialsImpl());
s3Client.setEndpoint("https://s3.mylocalaws.com");
S3Object resource = s3Client.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
```

Comment: What kind of service is this custom endpoint pointing to? Are you running some sort of local S3 compatible service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Choosing a Specific Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html) in the documentation.

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2(myCredentials); 
ec2.setEndpoint("https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

Comment: Thats confusing ... I've tried this with S3. First it accessed an object like https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/key. With that one line you've postet, it tries to get this object from a subdomained address like "bucketname.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com". like the bucket was configured for static page hosting and it fails.

Comment: OK that helped a little. I was confused about the URIs the SDK uses. https://bucket.base/key is correct. thanks